# Is it true brahma masturbated to urvasi and collected semen in pot and saraswati was born from it?

Tags: brahma, saraswati, matsya-purana

I have seen many people claiming this but i couldn't find the story in any puranas. Are they just rumours or is there really some story. If yes please quote the exact verse.

Comment: This is the story from bhagavatam - "Upon seeing Urvasi,  both Mitra and Varuṇa discharged semen, which they preserved in an earthen pot. The two sons Agastya and Vasiṣṭha later appeared from that pot, and they are therefore the common sons of Mitra and Varuṇa."

Comment: @kākatālīya Though it doesn't specify whether it's intentional discharge. It could be unintentional from arousal, like in dreams.

Comment: @Ikshvaku, most Deva births are ayonija and divya. Using words like semen (instead of veerya) that has human connotations will lead laymen to think/deride our devatas (see OP's title for instance) - the fact that they were born from a kumbha (pot) which is Amanushya (supernatural) will be conveniently left off. That's why we have to be extremely careful before translating to English and publishing to large audience.

Comment: @ram I see. And yes translators should also write commentry whenever necessary to avoid misinterpretations

Comment: That doesn’t sound right due to errors in translating as mentioned above